# IE Javascript style display not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs, the display attribute of one is by default block and the other one none. When you click a button the displays switch, so one hides and the other one shows. It works in every browser except in IE. Any idea of why this happens? Does it have something to do with the problem of IE with innerHTML? I will paste the js and the html

**JavaScript**:

```
function show(id, elm){
    var hide = document.getElementById(id);
    var show;
    var closeIcon = document.getElementById("closeIcon");
    if(id.substring(0, 3) != "set"){
        elmName = "set"+id.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + id.substring(1, id.length); 
        if(id != "video")   hide.style.display = "none";
        show = document.getElementById(elmName);
        show.style.display = "block";
        $("#instruccionBox").hide();
        $("#flechaEdit").hide();
    }else{
        elmName = id.substring(3, 4).toLowerCase() + id.substring(4, id.length); 
        hide.style.display = "none"; 
        show = document.getElementById(elmName);
        show.style.display = "block";
        $("#instruccionBox").show();
        $("#flechaEdit").show();
        skipStep();
    }

    if(id.substring(0, 3) != "set" && id != "meta" && id != "fechaLimite"){
        $('#closeIcon').show();
        closeIcon.style.left = $(show).width() - 45 + "px";
        closeIcon.style.top = "0px";
        show.appendChild(closeIcon); //alert(show.id);
    }

}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="grid_4 proyectoDonaciones" id="meta">
    <img src="images/edit-icon.png" alt="" class="editIcon" style="position:absolute; display:none"  id="editMeta" onclick="show('meta')"/>
    <h1 class="letter border1-pad2">META</h1>
    <!--div class="triangulo_izq_claro"></div-->
    <div> 
        <img src="images/cabezaIguana.png" alt="" width="70" class="editIcon" style="position:relative; left:12px;" onclick="show('meta')" id="cabezaMeta"/>
        <div class="donacionesBarra">
            <div style="margin:0 0 -60px 40%;"><h2 id="porcentajeMeta">0%<h2></div>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr height="45">
                    <td id="metaLeft" bgcolor="#a4c547" width="0%"></td>
                    <td id="metaRight" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%"></td>
                    <td><img src="images/colaIguana.png" alt="" width="70" style="position:absolute; left:250px;"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><span style="float:right;"><h3 style="color:#839e38;">$</h3></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><span style="float:right; font-size:15px;">of $<span id="metaText">9000</span> Goal</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="grid_4 proyectoDonaciones" style="margin-top:10px; display:none;" id="setMeta">
    <h2 style="margin:10px;">Escriba la meta</h2>
    <div style="margin:10px 25px 10px 10px;"> 
        <input type="text" id="inputMeta" value="9000" style="width:100%;" class="pro_form2" / >
        <br />
        <center>
            <input type="button" value="ACTUALIZAR" class="pro_btn pro_warning" onclick="show('setMeta', document.getElementById('closeIcon'))" />
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you using pure js if you already loaded jQuery? Use jQuery everytime because it's browser compatible in almost all situations

Comment: Hi, I already tried with $(elm).show() but it also doesnt work

Comment: try `$('#' + elm).show()`.. should work

Comment: yes, I did that, still not showing

Answer (score 0):

Your button is trying to show the div in which it is hidden!

You need to target the correct div e.g.

```
<div id="firstDiv" style="border:1px solid red;">
    first div here
    <input type="button" value="show second" onclick="$('#secondDiv').show();$('#firstDiv').hide()" />
</div>
<div id="secondDiv" style="display: none; border:1px solid blue;">
    second div here
    <input type="button" value="show first" onclick="$('#firstDiv').show();$('#secondDiv').hide()" />
</div>
```